# There is a error shown when Flutter firebase app connect with dialog flow

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage, dialogflow-es, flutter-dependencies

Because `firebase_storage ^8.1.3` depends on `firebase_storage_web ^1.1.2` which depends on `http ^0.13.0`, `firebase_storage ^8.1.3` requires `http ^0.13.0.`
And because flutter_dialogflow >=0.1.3 depends on http ^0.12.0+2, firebase_storage ^8.1.3 is incompatible with flutter_dialogflow >=0.1.3.
So, because lily depends on both flutter_dialogflow ^0.1.3 and firebase_storage ^8.1.3, version solving failed.
pub finished with exit code 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z2W4.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hPHy.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove versions numbers from each package and run `flutter pub get` to make the package manager resolve this conflict and get only compatible versions of this packages.

Comment: you are welcome, if this is the right answer please make this answer as the right solution